# Why to use SDL_gfx library to draw when I can just use SDL_RenderDrawLine

Tags: c++, sdl

So I am currently working on an physics engine and I have to draw stuff to the screen and heard about a sdl library called sdl_gfx. The thing I wonder is why would I use that library to render shapes on screen when I could do it by the methods provided by the base sdl library such as SDL_RenderDrawLine. To comprehend this, I searched for the "lineColor" function in the source code of the SDL_GFX library and obviously it does lots of other things than "SDL_RenderDrawLine" method. But I wish to know what is the difference.

Comment: `it does lots of other things than "SDL_RenderDrawLine" method` what other things? It sets colour and calls `SDL_RenderDrawLine`. You're probably confusing SDL_gfx (complimentary library for SDL 1.2) and SDL2_gfx (complimentary library for SDL2). In SDL 1.2 there were no rendering API and no `RenderDrawLine`. Most of older SDL_* libraries are not compatible with SDL2 as SDL's API have changed quite substancially.

Comment: Actually, I am talking about the SDL2_gfx. In an example code, I noticed that they use SDL2_gfx library's methods to draw objects. So what I wonder is, what are the probable issues I may face if I go with the base 'RenderDrawLine' method instead of using SDL2_gfx library.

Comment: If you can draw what you wanted without it - do it. As i've said, in simple cases like drawing lines - SDL2_gfx boils down to just calling 2-3 SDL functions. 'Harder' shapes like circles may require a lot more; if you need that shapes - it may be easier to use SDL2_gfx, but certainly not required.